# getting wether OS is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: c++, qt

getting information if operating system is 32-bit or 64-bit from Qt Framework, to be portable on different OS's

I can get from Qt information wether the application has been build for as 32 or 64-bit (QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture()) or wether the CPU is 32 or 64-bit (QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()), the operating system name(QSysInfo::prettyProductName()) but I haven't find how to determine if the operating system is 32 or 64-bit with Qt (should be portable!).
Is there any function in Qt to get that information?

Thanks for your time.

```
qDebug() << "QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture():" << QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture();
qDebug() << "QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture():" << QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture();
qDebug() << "QSysInfo::buildAbi():" << QSysInfo::buildAbi();
qDebug() << "QSysInfo::prettyProductName():" << QSysInfo::prettyProductName();
// the result with MinGW 32-bit:
// QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture(): "i386"
// QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture(): "x86_64"
// QSysInfo::buildAbi(): "i386-little_endian-ilp32"
// QSysInfo::prettyProductName(): "Windows 10"
// the result with VC++ 64-bit:
// QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture(): "x86_64"
// QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture(): "x86_64"
// QSysInfo::buildAbi(): "x86_64-little_endian-llp64"
// QSysInfo::prettyProductName(): "Windows 10"
```

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 8, "Requires a 64 bit platform");`

Comment: I have tried that, but if compile my code as 32 bit, I get 4 and not 8!

Comment: Ehh, yes. On a 32bit system you *would* get 4. That's expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although the name suggests otherwise, `currentCpuArchitecture` does not tell you whether the CPU is 32bit or 64bit, but will tell you about the bitness of the operating system.

> QString QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()
>
> Returns the architecture of the CPU that the application is running
>   on, in text format. Note that this function depends on what the OS
>   will report and may not detect the actual CPU architecture if the OS
>   hides that information or is unable to provide it. **For example, a
>   32-bit OS running on a 64-bit CPU is usually unable to determine the
>   CPU is actually capable of running 64-bit programs.**

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html#currentCpuArchitecture

Comment: @alainweiler It answers your question. The bitness of the operating system.

Comment: @Jesper
to be clear, I have a 64-bit CPU (Core i7 6700HQ) with Windows 10 64-bit, so for me its a 64-bit system. If I compile my application as 32-bit app (for example MinGW 32 bit) I get  sizeof(void*) == 4, if I compile with VC++ 64 bit, I get sizeof(void*) == 8.
And so, sizeof(void*) doesn't answer the question about the bitness of the OS

Comment: after many trials, I have found a solution, which gives also the right result with a 32-bit application running on Windows 64-bit.

Comment: @AlainWeiler obviously, `sizeof(void*)` is the size of the pointer of **your program**, not your OS. Now it depends on what you need to do to check the bitness of the program or the OS

Comment: @phuclv my question was about the bitness of the OS

Comment: @NineBerry the restriction stipulated in the documentation has prevented me to use that function.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I have found a solution, which gives also the right result with a 32-bit application an 64-bit Windows:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
inline bool isWow64Process()
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process

    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;

    //IsWow64Process is not available on all supported versions of Windows.
    //Use GetModuleHandle to get a handle to the DLL that contains the function
    //and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the function if available.
    LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(
                GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),"IsWow64Process");

    if( NULL != fnIsWow64Process )
    {
        if (!fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64))
        {
            // we couldn't get the pointer to the function,
            // we assume that app is not running as 
            // WOW64 process and return therefore FALSE
            bIsWow64 = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return bIsWow64;
}
#endif  // (_MSC_VER)

QString osInfo()
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QString osBitness( QSysInfo::buildAbi().contains("ilp32") && !isWow64Process()? "32-bit" : "64-bit" );
    return QString( QSysInfo::prettyProductName() + " - " + osBitness);
#else   // we do not know how to get OS bitness on Linux and OS-X (we do not mean processor, neither application, but OS!)
     return QSysInfo::prettyProductName();
#endif
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about my solution using `currentCpuArchitecture`?

Comment: @NineBerry just the warning in the Qt documentation, see above!
I have no PC with 32-bit Windows and 64-bit CPU, may be somebody could make the test